# Get Rid of pull-down arrow from top and bottom of Iphone Screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an app with lots of gestural interaction.  There are interactive touch areas situated in all areas of the screen.  The app is an interactive synthesizer and not some picture sharing network that tightly follows the human interface guidelines.

Whenever I interact with any of the gesture inputs near the top or bottom of the screen, these arrows that signal the OS info screens appear.  Is there any possible way to turn this off?

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that this is **not possible**.

The best you can do is warn users and ask them to go to settings to turn the Control Center off.